# Javascript: user confirmation when leaving single-page application

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I would like to make the user confirm that she wants to leave my single-page application. ExtJS 4.1 provides the [`onWindowUnload`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.EventManager-method-onWindowUnload) in which I would like to plug in a [`Confirm` dialog](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.window.MessageBox-method-confirm).

If the user decides to proceed closing the tab/window an [Ajax request](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.Ajax) to the logout URL should tell the server-side that the user has logged out.

Is the above approach possible?

Is it possible to plug the `onWindowUnload` event in ExtJS [`MVC controller`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller)?

**P.S.** *User leaving single-page app* can be any of the following: browser tab close, browser window close, browser back button, browser forward button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a listener to the window's `onbeforeunload` event.

It is a special type of event handler, and you should read the docs closely.

MDN docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

MS docs: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536907(v=vs.85).aspx

Ext's standard way of attaching event handlers DOES NOT WORK† with this particular event.

You need to use the standard `addEventListener` or `attachEvent` methods.

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/NhLQK/9/

- Can I use my own dialog? No
- Can I display my own message in Firefox? No
- Can I use a confirm()? No
- Can I make them look the same in different browsers? No
- Can I fire an AJAX message before the user closes the browser? Yes,
  if it's `synchronous`:

  Ext.Ajax.request({
    url:'some url',
    async:false,
    method:'POST'
  });

† it seems to work in Chrome with ext 4.1.1

Comment: Works! Still no idea how to put plug it to the ExtJS controller though; had to put this in the main `app.js` file that specifies the [`ExtJS application`](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application).

Comment: I did try to attach plug a handler to the `unload`  event, but the Ajax request to log out apparently never makes it in time :(

Comment: firing it in onbeforeunload seemed to work in jsfiddle for me

Comment: I need to plug the "logging off" to the `unload` event, as if the user decides to "stay on the web site" then I shouldn't be logging him off :)

Comment: Awesome stuff. I tried it on, and works with, Firefox too. Can't test it with MSIE as I'm running Ubuntu.